I'm developing a Flutter web app where I need to load content from a private URL (HTTPS) that requires specific trust anchors
I have implemented WebView in my Flutter app to load content from a private HTTPS URL. However, in both cases, I encounter a trust anchor issue. The specific error message I receive is:  `
I/cr_X509Util(32672): Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
E/chromium(32672): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(878)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202`.

